# CSS border overlapping with sidebar and header

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make it so that I have a border on the header and sidebar which connect, but don't overlap.

This is my HTML as an example.

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my CSS as an example.

```
        #sidebar {
            position: fixed;
            background-color: blue;
            height: 100%;
            width: 128px;
            border-right: 10px solid black;
        }

        #header {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: blue;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
            border-bottom: 10px solid black;
        }
```

I have a bit of trouble putting my thoughts into words -- so I'm also going to provide an image of the desired result.

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rlPo.png)

I would also like this to work when the divs are transparent.

Comment: Could you further clarify please?

Comment: Essentially, with the code snippet I have now I'm getting this -- http://puu.sh/od7Pi/12e971dada.png opposed to http://i.stack.imgur.com/1rlPo.png -- I'm not sure how to make it so the border from the sidebar does not overlap with the header, or vice versa.

Comment: Albeit some of the solutions would work for solid colors, any idea what I would do if I wanted to make the sidebar and header transparent? edit: As in the border still overlaps if the divs are transparent -- http://puu.sh/od8Ac/d176a4a166.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the document, I also added `margin: 0;` to remove the space between the edge of the page and the header and sidebar.

```
<html>
  <style>
    body {
    margin: 0;
 }
 #sidebarLeft {
    position: fixed;
    height: calc(100% - 200px);
    width: 128px;
    border-right: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
    background-color: rgba(191, 63, 187, 0.5);
    margin-top: 100px;
}
#sidebarRight {
    position: fixed;
    height: calc(100% - 200px);
    width: 128px;
    border-left: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
    background-color: rgba(191, 63, 187, 0.5);
    margin-top: 100px;
    right: 0;
}
#header {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: calc(100% - 276px);
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
    background-color: rgba(191, 63, 187, 0.5);
    margin-left: 138px;
}
#corner {
    background-color: rgba(191, 63, 187, 0.5);
    width: 138px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;

}
#Bcorner {
    background-color: rgba(191, 63, 187, 0.5);
    width: 138px;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
#cornerTopRight {
    background-color: rgba(191, 63, 187, 0.5);
    width: 138px;
    height: 100px;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
#cornerBottomRight {
    background-color: rgba(191, 63, 187, 0.5);
    width: 138px;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: calc(100% - 276px);
    border-top: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
    background-color: rgba(191, 63, 187, 0.5);
    margin-left: 138px;
    bottom: 0;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="top">
<div id="corner">
</div>
<div id="header">
</div>
</div>
<div id="sidebarLeft">
</div>
<div id="sidebarRight">
</div>
<div id="bottom">
<div id="Bcorner">
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
</div>
<div id="cornerTopRight">
</div>
<div id="cornerBottomRight">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Albeit this would work for solid colors, any idea what I would do if I wanted to make the sidebar and header transparent?

Comment: Something like `opacity: 0;` would make the divs transparent. I do not know what the desired result would be though for you.

Comment: Sorry -- let me rephrase that. The border overlap still shows up if the divs are transparent. http://puu.sh/od8Ac/d176a4a166.png

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but no -- the borders would still overlap. http://puu.sh/od8Je/1dc4ffe13d.png I'm thinking of maybe separate divs for the borders?

Comment: @MarcelDoe Use `background-color: white;` It is just the same as a 'transparent' div and it doesn't show the overlap.

Comment: I'd want the sidebar to be colored, through, such as a transparent purple or something.

Comment: @MarcelDoe Ahh ok, I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: Actually, let me know what you come up with, the issue with @afelixj answer is -- http://puu.sh/odaiR/0d0918c32b.png -- it's darker in certain areas.

Comment: @MarcelDoe Got it. I'll edit the post. If it works for you, would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: So close! http://puu.sh/odbjN/ca33bd5cae.png Any ideas? I guess it might not matter once the website has a background on it..

Comment: Change `width` on `#corner` to `138px;`, and change `margin-left` on `#header` to `138px;`

Comment: Thank you so very very much! You got it! I really appreciate you taking time out of your day to work this out with me! Would it be cool if I asked you some other things too sometime?

Comment: @MarcelDoe Ya no problem!

Comment: Not sure if I should open a new question for this, but lets say I wanted to do the same thing for a footer at the bottom -- http://puu.sh/odcyt/c5257827d4.png would this still be applicable or would I have to do something else?

Comment: ahh also just found the issue with this, sadly it makes the page scroll from side to side..

Comment: Ya I did too. Change `width` in header to `calc(100% - 138px)`

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Any idea on if I wanted the footer to have the same thing going on? http://puu.sh/odcyt/c5257827d4.png

Comment: What would the height be for the footer?

Comment: Same height as the header -- I'd also like to add a sidebar on the right side (just as a test to see how this all works)

Comment: Ok got it. Editing now.

Comment: @MarcelDoe Is my answer what you wanted?

Comment: Yeah, that's the answer I wanted -- I'm trying to understand the CSS now. If I wanted only the footer and no right sidebar, I'd remove those divs of course -- but how would I make the footer and header stretch 100% without the page scrolling coming back? (asking just to understand, not because i want this done)

Comment: Huh, the code itself works in the preview but when I put it on a page, it falls apart. Odd.

Comment: Can I get a screenshot of it on the actual page?

Comment: http://puu.sh/odkcY/946d263155.png Yeah, it seems to be constantly shifting which corner is there/which isn't with every edit.

Comment: What browser are you using? Edit: Found it. In the css it has an lowercase `b` but in the div it is uppercase. Just make it so they both are the same. Edited main answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would put an outside border on the inside white space, as a separate container, instead of on the blue sidebar and header.

Comment: Could you by any chance clarify? Sorry, I'm a bit of a newbie and trying to understand what you mean :(

Answer (score 0):

Im new to html/css... but wouldnt adding a

```css
display: inline-block;
```

to the header work?

Answer (score 0):

id  #sidebar give margin-top : 100px;

```
<style>
body{ margin:0; padding:0;}
#sidebar {
        position: fixed;
        background-color: blue;
        height: 100%;
        width: 128px;
        border-right: 10px solid black;
        margin-top:100px;
    }

    #header {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: blue;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;

        border-bottom: 10px solid black;
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: Albeit this would work for solid colors, any idea what I would do if I wanted to make the sidebar and header transparent? edit: As in the border still overlaps if the divs are transparent -- http://puu.sh/od8Ac/d176a4a166.png

Comment: if header color and sidebar is different and remove border then design much better , check   , http://www.gurukirpagroup.com/

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

for the sidebar try this:

```
#sidebar {
        position: fixed;
        background-color: blue;
        top: 108px;
        height: calc(100% - 100px);
        width: 128px;
        border-right: 10px solid black;
    }
```

It moves down the sidebar so that it exactly overlaps the bottom border of the header, and shortens to sidebar to have 100% height alltogether.

Here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVYZXR

Comment: This still shows the border of the header. The desired result was to have a seamless transition.

Comment: Doesn’t even need calc, if you remove height completely, and add `bottom: 0` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{  margin: 0;}
#sidebar {
position: fixed;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 128px;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: .5;
    top: 100px;
}
#header {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: .5;
}
#sidebar:after, #header:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
}
#sidebar:after{
  bottom: 0;
  top: 10px;
  right: -10px;
  width: 10px;
}
#header:after{
  height: 10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  right: 0;
  left: 128px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/rncwzLj1/1/

Comment: Almost! http://puu.sh/odaiR/0d0918c32b.png The issue with this is that certain areas are darker than others when transparent.

Comment: answer updated with opacity [https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/rncwzLj1/](https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/rncwzLj1/)